# Does the return type of the C++ stream insertion operator need to be an std::ostream?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ostream

The following [code](http://cpp.sh/7wuy) containing overloads of `operator<<` compile on MSVC 2008 and gcc 4.6.3. Is it legal?

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    friend Foo operator<<( std::ostream& stream , Foo& foo );
    Foo operator<<( std::ostream& stream )
    {
        return *this;
    }
};

Foo operator<<( std::ostream& stream , Foo& foo )
{
    return foo;
}

int main()
{
}
```

Comment: It is legal. Now try using it.

Comment: Afaik, the operator can return anything, but usually the insertion operator returns again the stream (after passing the second parameter to it) so that you can chain them: `stream << foo1 << foo2;` With your operator, this will have strange effects.

Comment: Probably the only way in which this would be useful is to enforce that you can only write a `Bar` after a `Foo`, by returning a wrapper `ostream_expect_Bar` from `operator<<(ostream&, Foo)` and consume that in `std::ostream& (ostream_expect_Bar, Bar)`. Thus `std::cout << Foo() << Bar() << std::endl` is legal, but omit either `Foo` or `Bar` and you have an issue at hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly legal to overload `operator<<` while varying the return type - it just won't work properly for the common use of streaming your type alongside other types to C++ streams.

As an example...

```
Foo my_foo;
std::cout << my_foo << '\n';
```

...will have evaluation attempted...

```
operator<<(std::cout, my_foo).operator<<(std::ostream& ??? '\n' ???)
```

...the `'\n'` isn't an acceptable parameter to `Foo::operator<<(std::ostream&)`, so you'll get a compilation error.